# Using docker to emulate a network on a single computer

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Say, I have an application which runs in a network, on multiple computers, communicating with other instances of itself across a network. And I want to test it on a single machine and get each instance to believe that it's running on a separate computer, in a network. How can I do this via docker?

Comment: You can use bridge network mode to create virtual network and point server to server with its domain names. The system should use docker DNS resolver to map the names to internal IP and provide the communication.

Comment: What did you try? If you run docker containers on the same network they will be accessible. Using docker-compose you will have the same results.

Comment: You could use `docker-machine`. using `docker-machine` you could create multiple `virtual-docker-host` having different `IP`s on a single host. You could think it as virtual-machine for `docker` host.

Answer (score 4):

As "h" mentioned in the comments above, the bridge network driver does this for you.   This driver is the default one so if you run multiple containers on your host they should be able to access each other via IP.

If you want DNS resolution you will need to define a bridge network since the default one will not provide that for you.

Details at https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

Here's a simple demo using a custom bridge network:

Create the network:

```
$ docker network create mynet
```

Start some named containers on that network:

```
$ docker run --rm -d --name one --net mynet nginx:latest
$ docker run --rm -d --name two --net mynet nginx:latest
```

From each container you should be able to resolve and hit the other(s):

one -> two:

```
$ docker exec -it one ping two
PING two (172.18.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.098 ms
...
```

two -> one:

```
$ docker exec -it two ping one
PING one (172.18.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.192 ms
...
```

Cleanup:

```
$ docker kill one two
$ docker network rm mynet
```